# What is an idiomatic way to fill a user-supplied buffer when reading bytes?

Tags: io, rust

[`Read::read`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) returns the number of bytes that it actually read, which can be less than the requested buffer. In many cases, it is acceptable to make multiple calls to `read` in order to completely fill the buffer.

I have this code, but it seems pretty ungainly:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn read_complete<R>(mut rdr: R, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<()>
    where R: Read
{
    let mut total_read = 0;

    loop {
        let window = &mut buf[total_read..];
        let bytes_read = try!(rdr.read(window));

        // Completely filled the buffer
        if window.len() == bytes_read {
            return Ok(());
        }

        // Unable to read anything
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to read complete buffer"));
        }

        // Partial read, continue
        total_read += bytes_read;
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Is there a function in the standard library that will abstract this work away for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/980) mentioned in the other answer is accepted, implemented, and available in Rust 1.6.0, you can just use the [`Reader::read_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) method:

```
try!(r.read_exact(&mut buf))
```

Or, using the `?` operator [introduced in Rust 1.13.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/11/10/Rust-1.13.html):

```
r.read_exact(&mut buf)?
```

Answer (score 4):

> This answer applies to versions of Rust before 1.6.0

Not as far as I know.

Looking at the [`byteorder`](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) [crate's source](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/src/byteorder/new.rs.html#196-207), there's a `read_all` method defined there, too:

```
fn read_full<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(rdr: &mut R, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
    let mut nread = 0usize;
    while nread < buf.len() {
        match rdr.read(&mut buf[nread..]) {
            Ok(0) => return Err(Error::UnexpectedEOF),
            Ok(n) => nread += n,
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::Interrupted => {},
            Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e))
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Note that this deals with interrupted IO operations.

There's also a [proposed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/980), that was submitted several months ago, went to final comment period, then changed enough that it was taken *out* of final comment period and is waiting for another go-around.

It turns out that this is unexpectedly complicated.  :P